# Pass system property to spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

A library I need to use reads system property in the following way:

```
System.getProperty("library.system.property")
```

Is there any way to pass such a property to spring boot while starting the app or do I need to set it in the system?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can pass it on the command line:

```
java -Dlibrary.system.property=value -jar myapp.jar
```

Answer (score 10):

**Update 2020-01-08**

For spring-boot **2.2.2.RELEASE** while develop

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Dmy_system_properties=test1"
```

For spring-boot **1.5.x.RELEASE** or below  while develop

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Dmy_system_properties=test1"
```

For run as **jar**

```
java -Dmy_system_properties=test1 -jar service.jar
```

You can try with a runnable example, here https://www.surasint.com/spring-boot-pass-system-properties-in-command-line/

Answer (score 6):

you can also do it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("key", "value");
    SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class);
}
```

Comment: Put System.setProperty same you said it will run ok but i don't understand yet why must put it before SpringApplication.run() ?

Comment: You set a system property before running your application. Then inside your application you can use this system property.

Comment: Alas, that doesn't work for all properties. A few (notably `java.util.logging.manager`) _must_ be set prior to this.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using spring-boot maven plugin to execute the application, try (no line breaks)

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Xms2048m -Xmx4000m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m 
-Dlibrary.system.property=value"
```

Refer [maven plugin](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html) for additional details