# How to get the value from system property in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I am using following command to run my spring boot application

```
java -Dlibrary.system.property=value -jar myapp.jar
```

Currently, I am able to access it via following command like below

```
System.getProperty("library.system.property")
```

However I need to access it via any annotation in Spring something like

`@value(${library.system.property})`

I tried to use

```
    @Value("${library.system.property")
    private String property;

    @Bean
    public SampleProvider getSampleProvider () {
        return SampleProvider.from(property);
    }
```

But the value of the property is `null`. Do I need to use conditional bean or something?

Comment: `@Value("${library.system.property}")`  should work.

Comment: Spring Boot combines environment variables, system properties and command line arguments with registered configuration files and creates what it calls an "environment". This provides uniform access to all the above - your suggestion should work perfectly; does it not?

Comment: It is not working when i add @Value("${library.system.property}") in below code                                                                                                                              `@Value("${library.system.property}")
    private String property;                                                                                                                                           
 @Bean
    public void test() throws URISyntaxException {
        return testMethod(property);
    }`

Comment: Change your command to: `java --library.system.property=value -jar myapp.jar`

Comment: thanks it worked for me after passing the argument `java -jar myapp.jar --library.system.property=value` and accessing it via `@Value("${library.system.property}")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks all. Issue got resolved by changing the way of passing the argument through command line as below

```
java -jar myapp.jar --library.system.property=value
```

Accessing the value by below code snippet

```
@Value("${library.system.property}")
private String property;

@Bean
public SampleProvider getSampleProvider () {
    return SampleProvider.from(property);
}
```

Comment: `--library.system.property=value` are program arguments that are transformed by SpringBootApplication to application properties.
See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.command-line-args

The question was initially how to use System properties that are given in cli via `-D` flag.
You can refer to that question which seems to be a duplicate.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34297666/pass-system-property-to-spring-boot

Answer (score 18):

You can access the system properties using the following expression:

```
@Value("#{systemProperties['library.system.property']}")
private String property
```

You can also access the system environment using the following expression:

```
@Value("#{systemEnvironment['SOME_ENV_VARIABLE']}")
private String property
```

Lastly, if you are using Spring Boot you can refer to the property name directly as long as you are passing it in the command line. For example, if you launch the JAR like `java -jar boot.jar --some.property=value` you can read it as:

```
@Value("${some.property}")
private String property
```

Comment: To be notted that all that is passed with `--` syntax are not System properties but program arguments. What is System properties are the ones defines with a `-DmyApp.someProperty` flag before the jar file.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Configuration
Public class YourAppConfig {

    @Value("${your.system.property}") String prop
    @Autowired
    Public void LoadProperties() {
        System.setProperty(PROPERTY_NAME, prop) ;
    }

    @Bean
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
import org.springframework.boot.system.SystemProperties;
...
String propertyKey = "library.system.property";
String propertyValue = SystemProperties.get(propertyKey);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can access your data from properties file by using @ Value on your controller.
For example:
    @Value("${library.system.property}")
    private String property;

Now your value is in property,now you can use it anywhere.